# Migrating a huge live drupal 6 site to drupal 7 Server

Tags: migrations

I am having a drupal 6 based news site with almost 600 thousand nodes. We are currently building a new site on drupal7.

1. What are the ways to migrate the content from old to new?
2. What are the best practices?
3. What are the know issues?
4. Can data be migrated in chunks?

I did alot of reading online, didn't find anything to give me confidence. Hopefully there will be people here who have hands on experience in this.

Comment: I've done a lot of data migrations into Drupal and each one was very different. Maybe there's a better way, but I would approach it by writing a D7 module to import data from the d6 instance. Yeap, manual queries to the old database, creating and saving node objects with the drupal api in the new system. Make a field for the old node ID in case you have any problems down the road so you don't have to start over if you end up missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is already well covered in the Drupal [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/548922).